# How to stop outputing my own html source?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, haml

This may be the werdeist bug I've ever met.

I'm currently building a app for personal use on Ruby on Rails, and it's still a long way from done.
The main layout is as follows:

```
!!!
%html.uk-height-1-1
%head
    = render 'layouts/head'
%body.uk-height-1-1.uk-width-1-1
    = if user_signed_in?
        .alerts
            = render 'layouts/alerts'
        .navbar
            = render 'layouts/navbar'
    .uk-container.uk-height-1-1
        = yield
    = if user_signed_in?
        .footer
            = render 'layouts/footer'
```

The alerts and footer partials are still empty, the head partial is mainly the default code rails generates (minus the turbolinks) and the navbar partial is, well, a navbar.
The only change I made on the Application Controller was adding `before_action :authenticate_user!`, so only users logged in can see the main site.

But as I run my server, the following showed up:

[image: The site rendered on Chrome]

It outputs it's own html source code as plain text!
And does so twice: First, right after the navbar partial, and last after the footer partial.
I've never met anything close to this, and any attempt to find the source of this error was useless.
How can I stop this, or at least find the reason of this madness?

Comment: What is the filename of your view?

Comment: @fivedigit The layout is `application.html.haml`, the root is `home/index.html.haml`

Comment: Just a guess, but what happens if you replace both of the `= if` with `- if`?

Comment: @fivedigit I hate myself so much right now.

Comment: Don't hate yourself, blame your keyboard. ;) Did that fix it?

Comment: Great! Answered it with a bit of explanation, for future finders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace both of the `= if` with `- if`.

Lines starting with `=` also append the return value of the if statement to the view, which is a non-HTML safe string.

Lines starting with `-` are just evaluated as Ruby code without appending anything to the view.